# Identify all Substantives in a Text

Tags: python, nltk, lang

I am currently training for the ISTQB Testmanager. For this purpose i would like to use ANKI and its cloze deletions.

I would like to generate the Flashcards automatically, namely via a Python script. This script should replace all substantives with a cloze deletion.

My question is:

**How do i identify substantives in a text with a python script?**

Unfortunately the syllabus is not available in German. German has the big advantage that substantives are capitalized.

Comment: Even in German there are other words that start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at parsing or POS tagging (POS=part of speech e.g. verbs, nouns)

[pattern](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-en#parser) and [NLTK](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch05.html) provide packages for that.

An example from pattern:

```
>>> from pattern.en import parse
>>> print parse('I eat pizza with a fork.')

I/PRP/B-NP/O eat/VBD/B-VP pizza/NN/B-NP/O with/IN/B-PP/B-PNP a/DT/B-NP/I-PNP
fork/NN/I-NP/I-PNP ././O/O
```

An example from NLTK:

```
>>> text = nltk.word_tokenize("And now for something completely different")
>>> nltk.pos_tag(text)
[('And', 'CC'), ('now', 'RB'), ('for', 'IN'), ('something', 'NN'),
('completely', 'RB'), ('different', 'JJ')]
```

Once you have the information on which ones are substantives or *nouns* (which have POS tags starting with *N* usually), you can do cloze deletions on them. Note that POS-tagging isn't perfect, so performance will depend on how complete the text you're working on is. (I'm also assuming you're working in English, but there are POS taggers for many languages.)

Comment: exactly what i need :). I really dont understand why this question was downvoted.

Comment: I imagine it's because folks felt the question wasn't clearly described. More questions seem to be getting placed on hold these days for inadequately explaining (1) what exactly the problem is (e.g. your question doesn't tell us what you mean by 'substantive', though the comment about German gives us clues) and (2) what you've already tried to solve the problem (e.g. there didn't seem to be anything in your question about "I tried X and that didn't work").